# Unable to upload facebook profile picture (Uri) to Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get a profile picture from facebook and then store it in firebase storage. I am able to get the profile picture Uri, however, I am unable to upload the picture to firebase storage. The error message that firebase returns is: "An unknown error occured.." After debugging I also saw this message within the thrown exception object, "java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://graph.facebook.com..." I have searched online, but I wasn't able to find anything useful. It may be worth noting that I am able to upload other pictures to storage, so I believe the syntax is correct. I just run into problems when trying to store fb profile picture. Any sort of help would be appreciated!

```
private void saveFbData() {
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    final String id = user.getUid();
    Uri fbUserProfilePictureUri = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(125, 125);

    String firstName = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getFirstName();
    String lastName = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getLastName();
    StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child(id).child("ProfilePicture");
    filepath.putFile(fbUserProfilePictureUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Successfully stored Profile Picture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    UserProfileData uProfileData = new UserProfileData(firstName, lastName);
    mDatabase.child("UserProfileData").child(id).setValue(uProfileData, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: do you want store profile url in firebase or profile photo?

Comment: Hello Ameer, I am trying to store the profile photo in storage.

Comment: you have url of photo ? with is point to fb profile photo

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. In the code above I utilize the facebook sdk to retrieve the profile picture uri. I have tried uploading the profile picture as a url, but it doesn't make a difference. Plus, there are other areas in my code where I successfully upload photos as uri's to Firebase storage.

Answer (score 0):

According to the graph documentation, you have an invalid parameter take a [look at this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo).